# Custom directive with templateUrl and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been reseaching this issue for hours, and finally [i reproduced it on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gStg15A4yQDOz9YB8dcd?p=preview).

#### Here's my issue:

When a customized directive which using external resource as template is combined with ng-repeat, the view didn't render correctly while model changed.

In my example, clicking link will replace the model, but old data hasn't been cleaned.

And if i using `template: 'stringTemplate'` instead of `templateUrl: 'urlToTemplate'`, it just works fine.
Still no idea if it's a bug or something...

#### Partial code:

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.topics = [{
            content: 'Click here to change reply',
            replys: [{
                content: 'Reply test...',
            }]
        }];
    })
    .directive('topic', function() {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'topic.htm',
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.reply = function(input) {
                    scope.topic.replys = [{ content: '"Reply test..." should be replaced, but it\'s not!' }];
                }
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('reply', function() {
        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            // template: '<div><div ng-bind="reply.content"></div></div>' //this works fine
            templateUrl: 'reply.htm' // same content
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and it seems you're not alone in this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151

User ishw mentions, as a quick fix:

"For those who may have not realized it yet: it's because your ng-repeat is on the root element in your directive's template. Wrap your ng-repeat in any element and it'll be fine."

[I tried this with your plunkr and it seems to be working](http://plnkr.co/edit/vSI1rImNqhroq344Tta0?p=preview):

```
  <div> 
      <div class="topic" ng-bind="topic.content" ng-click="reply()"></div>
      <div ng-repeat="reply in topic.replys"><reply></reply></div>
  </div>
```