# angularjs ng-repeat in table "jump" outside the table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I am basically creating a `table` with nested `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-controller="PresetManageController">
  <table>
    <in-preset ng-repeat="preset in presetManage.presets"></in-preset>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the template of directive `in-preset` is

```
<tr>
  <td>{{preset.name}}</td>
  <td>一些属性</td>
  <td>
    <a href="">编辑</a>
    <a href="">删除</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Directive declaration

```
module.directive('inPreset', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'scripts/directive-templates/in-preset.html'
  }
});
```

But when I open the page, I found that all `tr`s jumped outside of the table.

[image: trs jumped outside table]

If I change `table` to div, then it works fine. I have checked all html tags are perfectly closed. It is damn hard to debug this issue. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you are using `ng-repeat` on a custom directive (set to replace). There are a few weird behaviors with ng-repeat and replacing directives ([see related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177738/custom-directive-with-templateurl-and-ng-repeat)).

Try to leave the `<tr>` in your html and change your directive to be on an attribute instead.

#### html

```
<table>
  <tr in-preset ng-repeat="preset in presets"></tr>
</table>
```

#### js

```
.directive('inPreset', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<td>{{ preset.name }}</td>',
  };
})
```

See the [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/xhm6fs8j/1/)

Comment: Since a directive template must have one root element, so in this case, you can only place only one `td` in the template. Which is not I want.

Comment: This plus the suggestions in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18601027/3191599) helped me solve the same problem the OP was experiencing.