# Custom directive with ng-repeat (outside and inside), replace and templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've checked various ressources and all leads to a bug that was closed long ago. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177738/custom-directive-with-templateurl-and-ng-repeat) is a similar issue, but I think mine is slightly different and persists up to at least angular.js 1.5.

I'd like to validate, if this is a new angular bug or if I missed something, since I'm relatively new to angular.

### My problem

Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hYFOH4GIwGTbnnkeOOnx?p=preview) for a short demo of the issue

I've got a directive `<infos>` rendered inside a `ng-repeat` block

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <infos></infos>
  </div>
</body>
```

The `<infos>` directive has a `ng-repeat` block on its first element

```
<div ng-repeat="(infoId, color) in item.infos">
  <p style="background: {{color}}">{{color}}</p>
</div>
```

The directive is loaded with `templateUrl` and `replace:true`.

```
  .directive('infos', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'infos.html'
    };
  })
```

### The unexpected result:

When rendered, the directives of all iterations of the surrounding `ng-repeat` are rendered on the last `ng-repeat` of the outside loop and not as expected on each iteration of the surrounding `ng-repeat`. Check the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hYFOH4GIwGTbnnkeOOnx?p=preview) demo for a better understanding, what's going wrong.

### Workarounds

I found several workarounds to the problem:

- Wrapping the `ng-repeat` element in the directive by any other element

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="(infoId, color) in item.infos">
    <p style="background: {{color}}">{{color}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Leaving away the `replace: true`
- Using `template` instead of `templateUrl`. Inlining the template code.
- Using `<script type="text/ng-template" id="infos.html">...` to load the template

There might be another solution, using the `$templateCache` but I couldn't figure out how to preload the template, yet.

Comment: so what is problem with removing `replace:true`? It was actually deprecated a long time ago anyway

Comment: Removing is no general problem but I wanted to have no extra non-standard DOM element in my output but use an element directive for better code readability.

Comment: can't always have what you want... many directives use attributes and they don't make code hard to read. You can always set style properties on custom elements also ... `display:block` for example

Comment: Sure, you're right. And thanks for the info, that `replace:true` is deprecated. I checked for the reasons on this and it seems logical to me. I'll rethink my usage of this. Nevertheless, I'm curious if this is a bug in angular or some error in my code.

Comment: its' a bug when you use a deprecated feature